# Most efficient way to filter print statements

Tags: java, jsoup

What would be the most efficient way to make it so instead of printing every 5 seconds, it'll print every time, on the 5 second check, only if the return of getPercentage is different?

To clarify my question, as it stands if the string printed is 50%, if 50% has already printed, I would like to make it so it waits for a change to print again.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Wooot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        needData();
        Report();
    }

    public static void Report() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        while (needData() == true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(getData("http://woot.com"));
        }
    }

    public static boolean needData(){
        return true;
    }

    public static String getData(String url) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get(); 
        String percent = doc.select(".percent-remaining").first().text();
        return percent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `while (needData())` is sufficient. Keep track of the last percentage printed. If it's the same the next time, don't print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to do this:

```
    String current = "";
    String temp;
    while (needData())
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        temp = getData("http://woot.com");
        if (!current.equals(temp))
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
            current = temp;
        }
    }
```